# How to determine a git branch source or find a merge commit

Tags: git

I have 3 main branches: `PROD`, `TEST`, and `DEVELOP` and developers work in feature branches that are created from the `PROD` branch. And then the feature branch is merged into the environment branches at the respective point in its lifecycle.

I am now seeing commits in `PROD` and `FEATURE` branch that should only exist in the `TEST` branch. I don't know if the `FEATURE` branch was incorrectly created from the `TEST` branch (and then merged into `PROD`), or if the `TEST` branch was merged into the `FEATURE` branch before the `FEATURE` branch was merged back into the `PROD` branch. Or possibly the `TEST` branch was incorrectly merged into the `PROD` branch before the `FEATURE` branch was created.

I've tried using gitk on both the `PROD` and `FEATURE` branches, which is how I'm seeing the `TEST` branch commits in those branches, but how can I determine when, who, and how this was messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see a nice pretty line graph between all your branches that you can scroll back in time to see what got merged where, use:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

If you want to investigate those fishy commits on the `PROD` branch, then you can just look at it's graph history which will include branch paths that were merged into it with:

```
git log PROD --graph --oneline --decorate
```

Answer (score 0):

[`git log`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) will show author, date, time, and commit message, if any

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --graph
```

will show the author and date of the commits/merges